# Get result row count for individual SELECT statements with UNION ALL in MySQL when using LIMIT

Tags: mysql, select, union-all

I need to get the row count for individual SELECT statements in an UNION ALL SELECT query that uses LIMIT. The MySQL docs are pretty clear about getting the **global row count** for the query (place individual SELECTs in parenthesis and place an SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS only in the **first** statement, then get FOUND_ROWS() the usual way). However, I also need the result row count for the **individual** SELECT statements. The query, simplified:

```
(SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `field1`,`field2` FROM `db`.`table1` WHERE `id`>1000)
UNION ALL
(SELECT `field1`,`field2` FROM `db`.`table2` WHERE `id`>1000)
UNION ALL
...
(SELECT `field1`,`field2` FROM `db`.`tableN` WHERE `id`>1000)
LIMIT 0,10
```

If SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is placed in **every** SELECT statement an "Incorrect usage/placement of 'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS'" error is issued.
Google this a lot, read related messages here, to no avail. Might be something really simple, I just can't get my mind around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS can be used on a query to return a single number into FOUND_ROWS().

You can get back counts doing this:

```
SELECT 'table1' AS tablename, COUNT(1) AS rowcount FROM table1 WHERE id > 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'table2' AS tablename, COUNT(1) AS rowcount FROM table2 WHERE id > 1
...
SELECT 'tableN' AS tablename, COUNT(1) AS rowcount FROM tableN WHERE id > 1
```

if that helps.

If you want to return the rows from the tables with a count then modify it:

```
SELECT field1, field2, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table1 WHERE id > 1000) FROM table1 WHERE id > 1000
UNION ALL
SELECT field1, field2, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table2 WHERE id > 1000) FROM table2 WHERE id > 1000
...
SELECT field1, field2, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tableN WHERE id > 1000) FROM tableN WHERE id > 1000
```

From your question, it's not precisely clearly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to get the number of results for each individual select, ALONG with the total number if results (that's why I used SQL_CAL_FIND_ROWS and it works neatly). Gave your first solution a try, and ran into this: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43912. If I'd manage to circumvent it, that would probably be it. The second solution works a charm, but involves a nested query with possible performance penalty (not sure how severe, working on a small database now), because the original WHERE clause is a lot more elaborate (id>1000 is just an example). Any thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: Forgot to mention: also, second solution is inconvenient because I need counts separately, NOT in every row.

Comment: Accepted the second solution as the closest to what I need, although it places counts in each row, but due to LIMIT there are counts the are not returned (because *rows* containing them are not returned). A combination of the two would have been ideal, if not for the above mentioned bug. Gave up, will do counting in separate queries. Thank you.